# Disable MvcSiteMapProvider caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, model-view-controller, mvcsitemapprovider

There seems to be automatic caching that happens with MvcSiteMapProvider. Is there a mechanism to disable caching? We have custom caching routines written and I want to run it through those instead of relying on any built in caching mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to call Refresh before render menu or sitemap.

```
<% var sm = Html.MvcSiteMap();
((MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider)sm.Provider).Refresh(); %>
....
<%: sm.Menu(0, 1) %>
```

Comment: Can I call `Refresh` from the controller too?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be there in the current version

Answer (score 2):

In MvcSiteMapProvider v4, the cache can now be extended or replaced with your own implementation. Have a look at the following blog post that I wrote.

[MvcSiteMapProvider 4.0 - Extending the Cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20160901110619/http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/13/mvcsitemapprovider-4-extending-the-cache)

Under the covers it now uses System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache, an abstract class that can be replaced by a cache manager of your choosing.

Comment: Website seems down. Anyway, how do we just turn off the caching?

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the source, a cache item is always created when the sitemap is built, storing the item in `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. The lifetime of this cache item is configured from a property in the configuration `cacheDuration`. If this attribute is omitted from the configuration, it defaults to 5. Try setting that configuration attribute to 0.

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="MvcSiteMapProvider" enabled="true"> 
  <providers> 
    <clear /> 
    <add name="MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         type="MvcSiteMapProvider.DefaultSiteMapProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider" 
         cacheDuration="5" /> 
  </providers> 
</siteMap>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Might just wait for the 3.0 final release and modify the source myself to remove caching. I'd prefer an option to disable caching though so that I can continue to easily update MvCSiteMapProvider as new releases are posted to CodePlex...

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but who cares:

```
        foreach (var c in from object c in HttpContext.Cache where ((System.Collections.DictionaryEntry)c).Key.ToString().Contains("__MVCSITEMAP") select c)
        {
            HttpContext.Cache.Remove(((System.Collections.DictionaryEntry)c).Key.ToString());

            break;
        }
```